# Segmentation fault in client program

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Simply doing the following results in a segmentation fault.
Could it be something with argv or argc?
Really lost. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MESSAGE "Not so important message"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    printf(argc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See answer below (there may be other errors though). But you can find this kind of problems with a debugger which will show you exactly _where_ the segfault happens. Also format your code properly, the formatting of the conditional code in `if(hp != NULL)`  is very poor.

Comment: thanks Michael, thanks, i'm aware that  if(hp != NULL) is not the condition I should be using but it's just that when I initially had it as if(hp == NULL), the seg fault still occured which confused me because I thought the segfault arose from trying to dereference a NULL hp, so I just wanted to see if(hp != NULL) would be true and "Here 6" would get printed but NONE of the print statements execute whether I use if(hp == NULL) or if(hp != NULL) so maybe the segfault is from somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(hp != NULL)
    {
    printf("Here 6");
    perror("Failed to get host by name!");
    exit(1);
    }
```

Why are you quitting if `hp!=NULL` ? It should be other way round. You are de-referencing null pointer after this incorrect check:

```
bcopy((char *)hp->h_addr, (char *) &server.sin_addr.s_addr, hp->h_length)
```

Change to:

```
if(hp == NULL)
    {
       perror("Failed to get host by name!");
       exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: thanks, i don't actually mean to quit if(hp != NULL) ... It's just that when I initially had it as if(hp == NULL), the seg fault still occured which confused me because I thought the segfault arose from trying to dereference a NULL hp, so I just wanted to see if(hp != NULL) would be true and "Here 6" would get printed but NONE of the print statements execute whether I use if(hp == NULL) or if(hp != NULL) so maybe the segfault is from somewhere else?

Comment: Do consider to accept the answer if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I only get a segfault if I don't supply a hostname as an argument. This makes sense as you try to call gethostbyname with the argument of argv[1], which will be a NULL pointer if no argument is supplied.

The reason you don't see any of the printf() messages is that the output is buffered, if you changed them to print to stderr (unbuffered by default) you would see them before the segfault.

Comment: Having a `\n` at the end of the printf format string also helps.

Comment: thanks c3st7n, I changed the conditional back to if(hp == NULL) and changed all the printf statements to stderr but I still have the same result. you're saying argv[1] will be a NULL pointer if no argument is supplied? How do I ensure that an argument is supplied?

Comment: You can check the value of argc, it will hold the number of arguments supplied (including the program name itself). So in your example, if you check if argc is not equal to 2, you can exit early.

Also, if you wanted, you could check if argv[1] is equal to NULL before accessing it, and handle a NULL value appropriately.

Comment: I tried doing that but strangely, the same error occured. Could it be something with how I run the program: david@david VirtualBox:~$ ./client_test localhost"

Comment: Sorry I can't seem to recreate your issue. As long as I specify the argument it runs ok. Can you post the updated source?

Comment: I've edited the program. Even with just the lines printf(argc); and return 0;, I still get a segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Comment: Printf cannot be called with just an int like that. You need a format string, and then your value. For example, printf("%d\n", argc);.

Comment: The first argument to printf is a char pointer, by passing argc, it will try access the memory address 1 (or 2 if you pass a hostname argument to it). See https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf for the details of printf.